# Angular Service Why are we injecting on constructor

Tags: angular

Why are we injecting service in constructor as a parameter like this?

```
import { HeroService } from '../hero.service'; 
constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }
```

Instead of passing as a parameter, why don't we inject inside constructor:

```
import { HeroService } from '../hero.service'; 
constructor() {
    this.heroService=HeroService;
}
```

Is it possible to do in the above way?

Comment: https://kendaleiv.com/typescript-constructor-assignment-public-and-private-keywords/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As, you can find in official docs,

`The parameter simultaneously defines a private heroService property and identifies it as a HeroService injection site.`

```
constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }
```

- When Angular creates a HeroesComponent, the Dependency Injection system sets the heroService parameter to the singleton instance of HeroService.
- You can tell Angular to inject a dependency in the component's constructor by specifying a constructor parameter with the dependency type. Here's the HeroListComponent constructor, asking for the HeroService to be injected.

**Note:**

- The component shouldn't create the HeroService with new. It should ask for the HeroService to be injected.
- You can tell Angular to inject a dependency in the component's constructor by specifying a constructor parameter with the dependency type. Here's the HeroListComponent constructor, asking for the HeroService to be injected.

**What happens if we dont follow that:**

If you donot want to use depenedency injection, you should create new instance of service everytime with required dependencies, which is something we dont want.

Also, we need to declare a new variable for that service

Eg:

```
export class HeroListComponent {
  heroes: Hero[];
  heroService;
  constructor()
  {
    this.heroService = new HeroService('', '');
    this.heroes = this.heroService.getHeroes();
  }
}
```

[**Here is a reference for the same**](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection)

Comment: will it work same way if i set public variable inside constructor and assign the service?

Answer (score 1):

No. Before the class is created Angular needs to know what providers it should inject, you cannot do that using the latter example.

Comment: constructor only instantiated after the class has been created right?

Answer (score 0):

Angular allows you to declare the parameter in the constructor so you don't have to write a lot of code every time you inject a service. It's just shorthand for your second example.

Also, you should inject it as a parameter as that allows you to easily unit test the component by providing a fake service and decouple your test code from requiring a real service with, potentially, real resources e.g. a database, fileserver etc.

Answer (score 0):

Even if your second example might work, I would not recomment you doing so, because using the injector all components will get the same instance of the service which they won't in your second example. So for example passing data between components using a service will not work anymore.